# Probability problem involving compound events.

Tags: probability

The problem is as follows:

> Four students $A,B,C,D$ get on an elevator on the first floor of a 6 story building. Each one is equally likely to get off (independently) on any of the remaining $5$ floors. Find the probability of an event $E$ that states $A$ gets off before $B$ and $C$ gets off before $D$ -- note if $A$ and $B$, or $C$ and $D$ get off on the same floor then it fails.

Here is what I have done:

First we can break this into two different events that have no impact on one another: $A$ gets off before $B$, and this has no impact on whether $C$ gets off before $D$.

Now in total, since anyone can get off on any of the remaining floors we have $5^4$ possible outcomes.

What we can do regarding the order of $A$ getting off before $B$ is imagine reserving two floors of the $5$ to compute the number of ways $A$ and $B$ could get off on different floors, and we can consider each of them $A$ having gotten off first. For similar reasoning we can argue that $C$ gets off before $D$ at the same probability thus:

$$
P(E) = \frac{\binom{5}{2}^2}{5^4}
$$

The only thing I am unsure of here is whether or not my assertion that $\binom{5}{2}$ is valid for saying that this is the number of ways $A$ can get off before $B$ because $A$ and $B$ are distinct and I am worried $\binom{5}{2}$ includes terms where $B$ gets off before $A$, but I am unsure. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, if $A,B$ get off on the same floor, that's a fail, yes?

Comment: Assuming that, then Hint:  $P(A<B)=\frac 12\times (1-P(tie))$ by symmetry.

Comment: Yes sorry I will edit the question to make this more clear. If $A$ and $B$ get off at the same floor it shouldn't count.

Comment: I figured that's what you meant, but it is worth clarifying.  Do you understand my hint?

Comment: Also you should specify that they get off independently.  That's pretty clearly what you intend, but it does not follow from what you said.

Comment: I think so. By $P(tie)$ do you mean the probability that they get off at the same floor?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation you did is right